# How can I estimate the max PWM frequency can be generated by this microcontroller board?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, pwm

I have [this](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f302r8.html) Nucleo board which uses an STM32F302R8 MCU. At [this site](https://www.keil.com/dd2/stmicroelectronics/stm32f302r8tx/) and [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f302r8.pdf) it says:

[image]

What would be the reliable max PWM frequency achievable?

**EDIT:** I want make an adjustable PWM(so that I can adjust between 3 MHz to 10 MHz) with max 10 MHz freq, with resolution of 100 kHz(I guess 1%). I then need to find a micro board. So I need to estimate the max clock speed of such an STM32 board. What would be a max
clock freq for this case?

Comment: You look at what the clock/oscillator and timer registers do in the Reference Manual, not datasheet. Nothing else is reliable

Comment: In case you need a constant duty cycle **and** 0.1 MHz resolution up to 10 MHz, you need an unrealistically fast master clock, so that sort of disqualifies sourcing the pulse train directly from the MCU. You could build a comparator based oscillator and control it with a slow DAC

Comment: @tobalt is there a more accurate IC type that I can control freq by analog input?

Comment: VCOs are not capable upto that high freq https://www.renesas.com/br/en/document/dst/icl8038-datasheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want make an adjustable PWM(so that I can adjust between 3 MHz to 10
> MHz) with max 10 MHz freq, with resolution of 100 kHz(I guess 1%). I
> then need to find a micro board. So I need to estimate the max clock
> speed of such an STM32 board. What would be a good clock freq for this
> case? Thanks

Simple:

`I guess 1%` if your PWM granularity is `1%` then you need to multiply your maximum PWM frequency (`10MHz`) by `100` so the timer needs to be driven by the 1GHz clock.

If you use STM32 look for the models (F3, G4, H7) which have HRTIM (***H***igh***R***esolution***TIM***er)

Answer (score 2):

The question of PWM frequency is not only dependent on the clock frequency and number of bits in the timer, but also on the resolution of PWM duty cycle you desire.  For example, if you want to be able to adjust your duty cycle in 1% increments, you would need your timer to count a minimum of 100 counts per each cycle, so your maximum PWM frequency would be 1/100 of the clock frequency.  PWM for an application like motor control usually requires relatively high resolution so that minor adjustments can be made, when compared to an application like a dimmer where there is no need for fine control.

Comment: I want make an adjustable PWM(so that I can adjust between 3 MHz to 10 MHz) with max 10 MHz freq, with resolution of 100 kHz(I guess 1%). I then need to find a micro board. So I need to estimate the max clock speed of such an STM32 board. What would be a good clock freq for this case? Thanks

Comment: @GNZ John tried to emphasize that the desired **duty cycle resolution** is critical. Also based on your comment, you must specify over which the time scale you need the frequency accuracy.

Comment: @tobalt is correct.  For a 1% adjustment and you would need 100 x 10 MHz or 1,000 MHz.  Looks like that when you use PLL, you can get to 144 MHz with this device, so you could have 3/144 or about 2% resolution PWM at 3 MHz, but only 10/144 or 7% resolution at 10 MHz.  Another way of looking at it is that you would have 48 discrete duty cycle values at 3 MHz, but only 14 at 10Mhz.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead "when you use PLL, you can get to 144 MHz with this device," Where did you get this info? I thought max clock is 72MHz

Comment: I'm not that familiar with this device, but on page 21 of your linked data sheet there is a note at the bottom that seems to infer this.